# Automator Service - prevent multiple calls

Tags: applescript, automator, script

I might need some help.

I have an Automator Service / Script, which does basically just toggle play/pause in some application. I call this script via Shortcut.
I am using this to play/pause Spotify, because since Apple changed the behavior of the "play" key on the keyboard in the latest MacOS Versions, which does only react to the last active window with playing audio, and basically never does what it is supposed to do, or used to do in the past.

My problem is, when I call it with the shortcut it gets started so many times, that it is not predictable which state I will be.

I thought about putting an delay into the script, but apparently it does not prevent the script from running multiple times. So, how would I achieve this?

I tried to Google this, because it is actually a common problem in programming. But I know literally nothing about apple script and how to prevent multiple instances.

Maybe you can help.
Best Regards.

Code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

  tell application "Spotify"
    playpause
    delay 1
  end tell

  return input
end run
```

Comment: It might be useful for us to see the script...

Comment: Added the code to underline the question.